# Getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in below code. I am not calling any inbuilt str

Tags: python-3.x, appium, python-appium

```
Below is my Appium code to invoke the Settings
```

def invoke android(self)
caps = {
"platformName": "Android",
"platformVersion": "11.0",
"deviceName": "Pixel 5 Emulator",
"appPackage": "com.android.settings",
"appActivity": "com.android.settings.Settings"
}

```
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", caps)
time.sleep(3)
links = driver.find_elements(AppiumBy.CLASS_NAME('android.widget.TextView'))

for link in links:
    print(link.text)
    if link.text == "Network & internet":
        link.click()

time.sleep(4)
driver.quit()


**Getting error in below code:**
links = driver.find_elements(AppiumBy.CLASS_NAME('android.widget.TextView'))
E   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs found [here](https://appium.github.io/python-client-sphinx/webdriver.html), your usage of CLASS_NAME is wrong. CLASS_NAME is not a function. The usage you are after looks more like the following:

```py
links = driver.find_elements(AppiumBy.CLASS_NAME, 'android.widget.TextView')
```